# Menu responsivo com Bootstrap

Tags: html5, bootstrap-4

Bom dia! Galera estou fazendo um site e sou iniciante. Estou com problema no meu menu responsivo e no rodapé. 
Bom o problema do menu responsivo é que  o menu hamburguer está com problema ao clicar ele não abre as opções só abre se clicar quase no limite dele. E o problema do rodapé é que ele desaparece na tela do celular. Me ajudem por favor. Segue o código da página index.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet"href="css/style.css">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="imagens/favicon.ico" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">

    <title>Wolf Machine</title>
</head>

<body >
<header class="container-fluid">
<!--MENU-->
    <nav  id="menu" class="  navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark">

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                <li class="nav-item active"><a class="page-link" href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="page-link" href="sobre/sobre.html">BANDA</a> </li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="page-link" href="videos/videos.html">VÍDEOS</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="page-link" href="albuns/fotos.html">FOTOS</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="page-link" href="contato/faleconosco.php">CONTATO</a></li>
            </ul>

        </div>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"></a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="submit" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
                aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <div class="logos">
            <a href="https://www.instagram.com/bandawolfmachine1933"target="_blank"><img src="imagens/ic_instagram.png"></a>
            <a href="https://www.facebook.com/wolfmachineband" target="_blank"><img src="imagens/ic_facebook.png"></a>
            <a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCgTQD3hsartcobx-XvChAfg" target="_blank"><img src="imagens/ic_youtube.png"></a>
            <img class="lobo-topo" src="imagens/logo_wolf_topo.png">
        </div>
    </nav>


</header>

<!--Banner-->
<div id="rotativo" class="container">
    <div id="banner" class="carousel slide carousel-fade" data-ride="carousel">
        <!--Indicadores-->
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#banner" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#banner" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#banner" data-slide-to="2"></li>
            <li data-target="#banner" data-slide-to="3"></li>
            <li data-target="#banner" data-slide-to="4"></li>
            <li data-target="#banner" data-slide-to="5"></li>
        </ol>
        <!--Slides-->
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="carousel-item active">
                <img class="d-block w-100" src="imagens/foto_principal.png">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <img class="d-block w-100" src="imagens/banner_wolf_1.png">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <img class="d-block w-100" src="imagens/banner_wolf_2.png">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <img class="d-block w-100" src="imagens/banner_wolf_3.png">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <img class="d-block w-100" src="imagens/banner_wolf_4.png">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <img  class="d-block w-100" src="imagens/banner_wolf_5.png">
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
    <!--contraladores-->
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#banner" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Anterior</span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#banner" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Próximo</span>
    </a>



</div>
<!--Video -->
<div class="container">
    <h3 class="h3">Música autoral - Lobo Solto</h3>
</div>

<div id="video" class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">

    <iframe id="videohome" class="embed-responsive-item"  src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/e73PVzDVznA" frameborder="0"
            allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>

</div>
<!-- rodapé-->
<footer class="container-fluid mt-5">
    <div class="container">
        <div class=" row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 d-none d-md-block text-center">
                <p>&copy;Copyright-Joice Santos</p>
                <p class="pages"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/joice.santos.5832" target="_blank">Facebook</a>|
                    <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/joice-santos-a483036a" target="_blank">Linkedin</a></p>
                <p>Design-João Amaral</p>
                <p class="pages"><a href="https://www.behance.net/Ankhjoao" target="_blank">Portifólio</a></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</footer>

<!-- Optional JavaScript -->
<!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Reproduzindo aqui o código, não percebi nenhum problema no menu hamburguer, mas no caso do rodapé, basta remover as classes `d-none` e `d-md-block` da terceira div dentro do footer.

A classe `d-none` torna a div oculta, mas a classe `d-md-block` faz com que a div fique visível apenas em resoluções `md` (de `768px` pra cima). Como em mobile a resolução costuma ser menor do que `768px`, vai prevalecer a classe `d-none`, que torna a div oculta.

Comment: Obrigada o rodapé funcionou... não sei qual o problema do menu. O menu não está tendo um foco nele todo nem no meu navegador nem no celular, só funciona se eu clicar bem no cantinho direito. Infelizmente isso pro usuário final não fica bom.

Comment: e só esta acontecendo isso na página index. depois que acesso as outra abas  funciona perfeitamente.

Comment: Veja no inspecionar elementos do navegador se tem algum elemento cobrindo o menu.